# Python json encoding with classes that need custom encoders but which may themselves have nested data structures

Tags: python, json

This is obviously a simplified version of what I am trying do but ... let's say I have a

```
class X(object):
    pass

x = X()
y = X()
x.val = {1:2,3:4}
y.val = {1:2,3:x}
```

How do I write a custom json encoder so that it recurses through the encoding loop naturally ? I do not need the json to demonstrate that the class is of type X, (a dot dict will be fine). The actual example of this may have data structures nested 10 deep.

Obviously I could just override the default() method, but this does not seem to allow recursive calls - ie the best I have is some mess like this (and I need to json.loads otherwise the thing gets double quoted / escaped):

```
class XEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, X):
            return json.loads(self.encode({x:getattr(obj,x) for x in dir(obj) if "__" not in x}))
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Comment: Why are you using `setattr` instead of just `x.val = {1:2,3:4}`?  That adds needless confusion to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe over kill but I used to used a Mixin  class as follow:

```
def _default_json_encoder(obj):
    """ Default encoder, encountered must have to_dict method to be serialized.  """
    if hasattr(obj, "to_dict"):
        return obj.to_dict()
    else:
        raise TypeError('Object of type %s with value of %s is not JSON serializable' % (type(obj), repr(obj)))

class MixinJSONable(object):
    """
    Mixin pattern to add a capability to an object to be jsonable.

    If object have to_dict method it will be used to produce the dict, otherwise
    MixinJSONable.to_dict will be used.

    Only "public" attributes will be dump and instance of self._jsonable tuple.

    Attributes could be ignored by passing ignored_keys parameter to to_json method.
    Thus _ignored_json_keys (class attribute) will be update and spread over all class using this Mixin.

    """
    # _ignored_json_keys = list()

    def to_dict(self):
        """
        to_dict method to dump public attributes.
        """

        self._jsonable = (int, list, str, dict)

        _dict = dict()
        for attr in dir(self):
            value = getattr(self, attr)
            if attr.startswith("_") or attr in getattr(MixinJSONable, "_ignored_json_keys", []):
                continue
            elif isinstance(value, self._jsonable) or value is None or hasattr(value, 'to_dict'):
                # to_dict method is used as serialization method.
                value = value
            else:
                continue
            _dict[attr] = value
        return _dict

    def to_json(self, **kw):
        """
        Dump object as Json.

        Accept the same keys than :func json.dumps:. If ignored_keys (list) is passed,
        the keys will not be dumped in the json (filter over all sons)

        """
        indent = kw.pop("indent", 4)  # use indent key if passed otherwise 4.
        _ignored_json_keys = kw.pop("ignored_keys", [])
        if _ignored_json_keys:
            MixinJSONable._ignored_json_keys = _ignored_json_keys
        return json.dumps(self, indent=indent, default=_default_json_encoder, **kw)


class X(MixinJSONable):
    pass

x = X()
y = X()
setattr(x,"val",{1:2,3:4})
setattr(y,"val",{1:2,3:x})
y.to_json()
```

will print:

```
{
    "val": {
        "1": 2,
        "3": {
            "val": {
                "1": 2,
                "3": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so you had pretty much exactly the same problem !? Shouldn't the json / simplejson libraries allow re-entrant methods in the customised blocks ? Would that make for a better solution ?

Comment: I've started working on this, but I've found out that I'm actually pretty much writing a json encoder from scratch.. I'd really like to find a clever way to patch the existing json or simplejson libraries...

Comment: Yep keep me posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand the values and then encode the python structure?

```
class XEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        new_object = {}

        def expand_it(obj, X):
            blank_dict = {}
            try:
                data = vars(obj)
            except TypeError:
                data = obj
            data_keys = list(data.keys())
            for k in data_keys:
                if isinstance(data[k], X):
                    print(data[k])
                    blank_dict[k] = expand_it(data[k], X)
                elif type(data[k]) == dict:
                    blank_dict[k] = expand_it(data[k], X)
                else:
                    blank_dict[k] = data[k]
            return blank_dict

        new_object = expand_it(y, X)
        encoded_json = json.JSONEncoder().encode(new_object)
        loads_json = json.loads(encoded_json)
        return loads_json
```

Here's some output:

```
class X(object):
    pass

w = X()
x = X()
y = X()
z = X()

setattr(w,"val",{1:2,3:4})
setattr(x,"val",{1:2,3:w})
setattr(y,"val",{1:2,3:x})
setattr(z,"val",{1:2,3:y})

in_json = XEncoder().encode(z.val)
print(in_json)
```

> {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": 4}}}}}}}

Comment: That's a great start point, how about the example x2 = [1,x] , that seems to throw the is not JSON serializable exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but the `json.dumps()` default option handles recursing through an object graph just fine.

If don't care about preserving the type of the originating object:

```
def jsondefault(obj):
    return dict(obj.__dict__)
```

If you want to remember the type of the object you're encoding:

```
def jsondefault_types(obj):
    result = dict(obj.__dict__)
    result['__type__'] = ".".join([
        obj.__class__.__module__, obj.__class__.__name__])
    return result
```

Then you can dump either way:

```
class X(object): pass
x, y, z = X(), X(), X()
x.val = {1:2, 3:4}
y.val = {1:2, 3:x}
z.val = {1:2, 3:y}

print json.dumps(z, default=jsondefault)
print json.dumps(z, default=jsondefault_types)
```

resulting in:

```
'{"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": 4}}}}}}'

'{"__type__": "__main__.X", "val": {"1": 2, "3": {"__type__": "__main__.X", "val": {"1": 2, "3": {"__type__": "__main__.X", "val": {"1": 2, "3": 4}}}}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`vars` does.

```
class XEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, X):
            return vars(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

test;

```
class X(object):
    pass

x = X()
x.val = {1:2,3:None}

def nest(obj,level):
    for _ in range(level):
        o = X()
        o.val = {1:2,3:obj}
        obj = o
    return o

XEncoder().encode(nest(x,10))
```

output;

'{"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": {"val": {"1": 2, "3": null}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}'

Comment: does not work if you pass a list of x, because the first object calls JSONEncoder.default()